# Connecting at Phone and Laptop together automatically (dot net)

Tags: c#, android, windows, bluetooth, wifi

I was wondering what the best way to open a data channel between a phone and a laptop doesn't have to guaranty that the packets make it (ie UDP) and only has to be one way laptop -> phone. This is to provide key live information that occurs in my software on the phone. old data is useless so a 'reliable' like TCP. The devices I want to support are Android for phone and Windows for the laptop. This application doesn't get used where a access point is available so the connection will be peer to peer. The current method I have is to get the user to setup a wifi adhoc connection on their laptop and connect there phone from there but this is to many steps and I would rather a zero config solution. It can use bluetooth or wifi. I am using dot net on both pc and android (xamiran). cheers

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to look at something on the lines of these the Network Service Discovery. I don't have an example to hand sorry but there seems to be ample of code examples and documentation.

**Android:**

*Network Service Discovery*

http://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/nsd-wifi-direct.html

**Computer App:**

*Network Service Discovery Broadcaster in C#*

[C# How to do Network discovery using UDP Broadcast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22852781/c-sharp-how-to-do-network-discovery-using-udp-broadcast)

Basically your app will listen to network broadcasts on the wifi (sent to the subnet mask) and if it gets one perform a given action.

Here are some relevant Stack overflow posts as well:

[Network Service Discovery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24188803/network-service-discovery)

Hope this helps!